# SQL to get all values from look up and corresponding values from master table

Tags: sql, join

i have 3 tables. A, B, C as shown.

```
Table A                | Table B                   | Table C
---------------------- | ------------------------- |--------------------------------
StudentId StudentName  |  SubjectId  SubjectName   |  StudentId   SubjectId   Marks
   1          Jack     |     101        History    |     1          101        33
   2          Peter    |     102        Science    |     2          102        75
   3          Samantha |     103        Literature |     3          101        55
----------------------- | ------------------------- | -------------------------------
```

I need a query to generate result against each subject as follows:-

```
 ------------------------------------
  StudentName  SubjectName     Marks
 ------------------------------------
   Jack         History         33
   Jack         Science         0
   Jack         Literature      0
   Peter        History         0
   Peter        Science         75
   Peter        Literature      0
   Samantha     History         33
   Samantha     Science         33
   Samantha     Literature      33
 ------------------------------------
```

i used following queries that did not produced desired result.

```
    1. select  a.StudentName, b.SubjectName, c.Marks from a, b, c
       where
            a.StudentId = c.StudentId
       and  
            c.SubjectId = b.StudentId

    2.  select  a.StudentName, b.SubjectName, c.Marks from a, b, c
       where
            a.StudentId = c.StudentId
       and  
            c.SubjectId = b.StudentId(+)
    3.select  a.StudentName, b.SubjectName, c.Marks from a, b, c
       where
            a.StudentId = c.StudentId
       and  
            (+)c.SubjectId = b.StudentId
```

My queries would miss out the subject whose marks would not be in table C. while i need all three subjects from table b to be repeated for every student. get marks where entered and show "0" where the subject is not entered against a particular student in TableC. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6a42/10) will give you what exactly you want. Below is the select Query.

```
select D.StudentName,D.subjectName,Isnull(C.marks,0) as Marks  from TableC C
Right Join
(select * from TableA A,TableB B
) D on C.studentID = D.studentID and C.subjectID = D.subjectID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT a.StudentName, b.SubjectName, c.Marks
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C
ON A.StudentID = C.StudentID
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.SubjectID = C.SubjectID
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the result OP is looking for. You need to include all courses for all students whether they have a mark or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use sql server, try this

```
SELECT A.StudentName, B.SubjectName, ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Marks 
                                      FROM C
                                      WHERE C.StudentId = A.StudentId AND B.SubjectId = C.SubjectId),0) as Marks
FROM A,B
Order By A.StudentName
```

Or

```
;WITH StudentCourses As
(
  SELECT A.*,B.* 
  FROM A,B
}
SELECT StudentCourses.StudentName,StudentCourses.SubjectName,ISNULL(C.Marks,0) as Marks
FROM StudentCourses LEFT JOIN C ON C.StudentId =StudentCoursesA.StudentId AND StudentCourses.SubjectId = C.SubjectId
```

If you use mysql, try this:

```
SELECT A.StudentName, B.SubjectName, IFNULL((SELECT Marks 
                                          FROM C
                                          WHERE C.StudentId = A.StudentId AND B.SubjectId = C.SubjectId),0) as Marks
    FROM A,B
    Order By A.StudentName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT a.StudentName, b.SubjectName, c.Marks
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
   ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN TableC c
   ON b.SubjectID = c.SubjectID
   AND a.StudentID = c.StudentID
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/456ab/3/0)